# Dropdown menu either moves content or does not let me centre it

Tags: html, css

I guess it's kinda easy, but I've been stuck here for 3 hours already.
My dropdown menu moves whole content when used. I searched for similar questions on StackOverflow, for questions related to dropdown menus and got the following answer that partly helped:

```
.menu > ol {  
  position:absolute;
  z-index:100;  
}
```

I've added the snippet above to the original code. It worked out somehow - it doesn't move other content but now I can't centre it horizontally. 
Using `margin:0 auto;` also did not help.
Could you please help me out? I've either placed position + zindex in wrong place, or I'm missing something. 
Codepen:
https://codepen.io/graphconcept/pen/MdwQBM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `position: absolute` from `.menu > ol` and add it to `.menu`. Also add `width: 100%` to `.menu`. If you want your menu to be visible regardless of scrolling make the position `fixed` instead and add `top: 0`.

```
.menu {
  margin: 15px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
.menu > ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index:100;  
}
```

Explanation:

Block elements with `position: static` (the default value for position) have a default width of 100%; Setting the position to `absolute` or `fixed` changes their width to `auto`; i.e. they shrink to fit their content's width. Your menu list is being horizontally centred within the menu element. This meant that when the menu element was 100% the width of the page, horizontally centring the menu list would also centre it with respect to the page. However when the menu element shrank to fit its width, the menu list couldn't be centred any more than it already was. The width of the menu element needed to be explicitly set to 100% to allow the centring to have a visible effect.

Comment: I would never get to this point, much love and thanks for explanation! <3